# Upload file using nestjs and multer

Tags: nestjs

Since nestjs is an express app, it's possible to use any library to handle upload using nest, and since it provides Midlewares, it's also possible to use multer. My question is: What's the best way to handle file uploads using nestjs?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As informed by @Kamyl on issue https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/262, since `v4.6.0` is possible to upload files using multer to nestjs using a common file interceptor.

```js
import { ... , UseInterceptors, FileInterceptor, UploadedFile } from '@nestjs/common'

... 
 
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
async upload( @UploadedFile() file) {
  console.log(file)
}
```

This way the variable `file` will have a `buffer`

---

#### Using Multer options

It's also needed the field name as the first param, then an array with Multer Options

```js
import { ... , UseInterceptors, FileInterceptor, UploadedFile } from '@nestjs/common'
import { diskStorage } from 'multer'
import { extname } from 'path'

...

@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {
  storage: diskStorage({
    destination: './uploads'
    , filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      // Generating a 32 random chars long string
      const randomName = Array(32).fill(null).map(() => (Math.round(Math.random() * 16)).toString(16)).join('')
      //Calling the callback passing the random name generated with the original extension name
      cb(null, `${randomName}${extname(file.originalname)}`)
    }
  })
}))
async upload( @UploadedFile() file) {
  console.log(file)
}
```

This way the variable `file` will have a `filename`, `destination` and `path`.

The `destination` param from the `diskStorage` can also be a function, with the parameters and expecting the callback the same as `filename`. By passing a `diskStorage` the file will be automatically saved to the destination informed with the filename given.

It's also possible to handle multiple files by using `@UploadedFiles` and `FilesInterceptor` (plural)

Comment: What is `const randomName` doing?

Comment: A crazy way to generate a randomic 32 charaters. You'd better use https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Comment: @VictorIvens can you please show how to change the file name with the latest packages.. Thanks

Comment: how to rename the image dynamically? assume when we create a new user and we need to upload the profile image and rename the image with userId or something?

Answer (score 32):

A cleaner way would be to extract the configurations to a separate file and then call it inside the interceptor method

```js
import { extname } from 'path';
import { existsSync, mkdirSync } from 'fs';
import { diskStorage } from 'multer';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';

// Multer configuration
export const multerConfig = {
    dest: process.env.UPLOAD_LOCATION,
};

// Multer upload options
export const multerOptions = {
    // Enable file size limits
    limits: {
        fileSize: +process.env.MAX_FILE_SIZE,
    },
    // Check the mimetypes to allow for upload
    fileFilter: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
        if (file.mimetype.match(/\/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
            // Allow storage of file
            cb(null, true);
        } else {
            // Reject file
            cb(new HttpException(`Unsupported file type ${extname(file.originalname)}`, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST), false);
        }
    },
    // Storage properties
    storage: diskStorage({
        // Destination storage path details
        destination: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
            const uploadPath = multerConfig.dest;
            // Create folder if doesn't exist
            if (!existsSync(uploadPath)) {
                mkdirSync(uploadPath);
            }
            cb(null, uploadPath);
        },
        // File modification details
        filename: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
            // Calling the callback passing the random name generated with the original extension name
            cb(null, `${uuid()}${extname(file.originalname)}`);
        },
    }),
};
```

and then call it under the interceptor like so

```js
import { ... , UseInterceptors, FileInterceptor, UploadedFile } from '@nestjs/common'
import { diskStorage } from 'multer'
import { extname } from 'path'
import { multerOptions } from 'src/config/multer.config';
...

@Post('/action/upload')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', multerOptions))
async upload( @UploadedFile() file) {
  console.log(file)
}
```

Comment: great solution! I liked you put all the pieces together

Comment: `multerConfig.dest` is undefined because `env` hasn't been loaded at the first time.

Comment: @DucTrungMai make sure you are loading your env files before your application boots up. To check this add this import in the beginning of your `main.ts` file `import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';` This ensures that the env is available for use before the app context is loaded.

Comment: Fileinterceptor(multeroptions) saves the file in the disk storage, whenever we call that request. What if there is issue in insert or update method. In that case I don't want to store the file in the disk storage. The file should be saved to disk storage only when the db insert or update method is success. How can it be done?

Answer (score 6):

## Cleanest implementation using Multer options

Thank you @VictorIvens for the best answer out of the bunch.

**However**, I found the following **problems** in the code.

- the import called `FileInterceptor` does not exist withing `@nestjs/common` package int the latest version of NestJS.
- the code looks a bit too cluttered to my eyes.

So, to **simplify** the things up, I have come up with the following solution.

**storage.config.ts**

```
export const storage = diskStorage({
  destination: "./uploads",
  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, generateFilename(file));
  }
});

function generateFilename(file) {
  return `${Date.now()}.${extname(file.originalname)}`;
}
```

**your-controller.controller.ts**

```
import {
  Controller,
  Post,
  UseInterceptors,
  UploadedFile
} from "@nestjs/common";
import { FileInterceptor } from "@nestjs/platform-express";

import { diskStorage } from "multer";
import { extname } from "path";
import { storage } from "./storage.config"


@Controller()
export class YourController {
  @Post("upload") // API path
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor(
      "file", // name of the field being passed
      { storage }
    )
  )
  async upload(@UploadedFile() file) {
    return file;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with your solution.

```
 @UseInterceptors(
  FileInterceptor(
   'file',
   { storage },
  ),
 )
```

throw me error:

`Argument type Type<NestInterceptor> is not assignable to parameter type NestInterceptor | Function`

Answer (score 3):

**

### 2021 Update

**

To do this now, you need to import FileInterceptor like this...

```
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the data from the user via API call, you can save the data as buffer and access the content using [adm-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip). Below is the controller method implementation in nest.js.

```
@Post("/blackBoardUpload")
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('image', {
      storage: memoryStorage(),



      fileFilter: zipFileFilter,

    }),
  )
  async uploadedFile(@UploadedFile() file) {
    console.log(file)
    const response = {
      originalname: file.originalname,
      filename: file.filename,
    };
    var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');
    var zip = new AdmZip(file.buffer);

    var zipEntries = zip.getEntries();
    console.log(zipEntries.length);
    
    return {
      status: HttpStatus.OK,
      message: 'Received Zip file successfully!',
      data: response,
    };
  }
```

Comment: This methods in AWS lambda throws this Error: Invalid CEN header (bad signature)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Create a helper.ts file that rename your file and contains path
        
    export class Helper {
            static customFileName(req, file, cb) {
              const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
              let fileExtension = "";
              if(file.mimetype.indexOf("jpeg") > -1){
                  fileExtension = "jpg"
              }else if(file.mimetype.indexOf("png") > -1){
                  fileExtension = "png";
              }
              const originalName = file.originalname.split(".")[0];
              cb(null, originalName + '-' + uniqueSuffix+"."+fileExtension);
            }
           
            static destinationPath(req, file, cb) {
              cb(null, 'uploads/')
            }
          }

code for controller

import { Helper } from '../service/Helper';
import { diskStorage } from 'multer';
import {FileInterceptor} from '@nestjs/platform-express'
import {Controller, Post, Body, UseInterceptors, UploadedFile} from '@nestjs/common'

    @Post('upload')
    @UseInterceptors(
        FileInterceptor('picture', {
            storage: diskStorage({
                destination: Helper.destinationPath,
                filename: Helper.customFileName,
            }),
        }),
    )

    uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
    console.log(file);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have written the code to upload single and multiple files using NEST.JS:**

**app.controller.ts:**

```
import { Controller, Post, UploadedFiles, UploadedFile, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FileInterceptor, FilesInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Express } from 'express';


@Controller('api/portal/file')


export class AppController {
  constructor(private appService: AppService) {}


  @Post('/multiple')
  @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files'))
  async uploadFiles(@UploadedFiles() files: Array<Express.Multer.File>) {
    const req = {
      files,
      prospectId: 1234,
    };
    return await this.appService.getUrls(req);
  }


  @Post('/single')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  async uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
    const req = {
      files: [file],
      prospectId: 1234,
    };
    return await this.appService.getUrls(req);
  }
}
```

**app.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FileDataReq, FileDataRes } from './dto/app.dto';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  async getUrls(uploadData: FileDataReq): Promise<FileDataRes> {
    const { prospectId } = uploadData;
    const response = { urls: [], prospectId };
    const { files } = uploadData;
    for (const file of files) {
      const { originalname } = file;
      let url = `/${prospectId}/${new Date().getTime()}_${originalname.trim().split(' ').join('_')}`;
      response.urls.push(url);
    }
    return response;
  }
}
```

**app.dto.ts:**

```
export class FileDataReq {
  files: any[];
  prospectId: number;
}

export class FileDataRes {
  urls: string[];
  prospectId: number;
}
```

**Postman:**

**Multiple Upload:**
[image]

**SingleUpload:**
[image]

Comment: If getting the error "Namespace 'global.Express' has no exported member 'Multer'" then replace "Array<Express.Multer.File>" with "any" or try to remove the error by installing Express/multer

Answer (score -3):

A simple way is to use controllers. You need to define an upload controller and add it in your app.module, this is an example of what a controller should be (back-end):

```
@Controller()
export class Uploader {
  @Post('sampleName')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file) {
  // file name selection 
    const path = `desired path`;
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path);  
    writeStream.write(file.buffer);
    writeStream.end();
    return {
      result: [res],
    };
  }
}
```

And call your controller by fetch in the front-end:

```
    fetch('controller address', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: data,
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((success) => {
            // What to do when succeed 
});
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log('Error in uploading file: ', error));
```